# Messages asking me permission to access the proxy data stored in keychain

Tags: permission, keychain, proxy

When connected to my office network, I keep getting messages asking me permission to access the proxy data stored in keychain. They keep popping up every few minutes (even seconds), no matter what I do.
I enter my keychain password and click on "Always", but the messages still appear. I click on "Deny" and they still come back!
And if I click on "Deny", nothing seems to happen: everything works fine alla the same... These messages look like they are perfectly useless...
I attach a screenshot.
[image]